# Can I use @WebMVCTest to load an @Component?

Tags: spring, junit

I've got tests in a Junit class annotated with @WebMVCTest, but one of my @Component classes is necessary to handle exceptions. How do I get my @Component in my JUnit class?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@WebMVCTest
@Import(YourComponent.class)
public MyTestClass {
}
```

Note that `@WebMVCTest` is to test controllers. You could mock other components like services, repositories, etc... to have a non dependent test (= a real controllers test).